# Encrypting parameters in wrapper.config

Tags: java, encryption, wrapper

I'm trying to secure a java app that I'm working on. This app has service wrapper that contains a list of parameters, among these a database password. So there are 3 solutions but I'm not sure that any one of them is possible.

1) encrypt the whole file without yet keep it usable.

2) store an encrypted password and add a encryption function to the file

3) create an external program that restores the encrypted password and call it's result in the wrapper.config file

After desperately searching the internet for a response I didn't find any helpful so I'm hoping to find someone who had a similar issue in here.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use a key store, as shown in [this](http://kingsfleet.blogspot.com/2008/12/storing-password-somewhere-safe.html) blog post, however you would still need to find a *safe* place to store the key to the key store itself. To go around this, you could make your application ask the user the password to the key store, this way the data will be secure but you do not store any (keystore) passwords. That being said, if you are willing to ask your user for a password each time the application switches on, one might as well simply ask the user for the DB password right away.

If you are encrypting the file, you would still need to ship the key with which the application will need to do the decryption. This would mean that potentially users would still be able to look into your application and decrypt the file as they please.

I think that if you *really* want a *safe* solution, the answer would be to simply *not* store the password yourself, but rather ask the users for the password each time.

Comment: That would be actually helpful if the password was stored in one of the apps files or if the users were supposed to know the DB's password. Unfortunately that's not the case. The problem that I'm concerned about is an external service. In a file called wrapper.conf with weird coding language. Thanks anyways for your suggestion.